# Nesting Linq query with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

When I try to run this piece of logic, NHibernate comes back with an error stating it has no reference to "Site".

```
IQueryable<Product> query = this.RetrieveAll();    
query = query.Where(x => x.Status == Product.Statuses.Approved || x.SiteProduct.Where(y => y.Site.ID == siteID).Count() > 0);
```

A little background.
Product has a One to Many Map to SiteProduct
SiteProduct has a One to Many Map to Site

Even a simpler version has issues it states it has no reference to ID:

```
IQueryable<Product> query = this.RetrieveAll();    
query = query.Where(x => x.Status == Product.Statuses.Approved || x.SiteProduct.Where(y => y.ID > 0).Count() > 0);
```

Does NHibernate have issues with nesting "Where" statements within itself?

As for the table mappings, they appear to be correct since I can transverse all the way down and capture individual records at the bottom through lazy loading.  Addition, Getting and Deleting records all works perfectly.  I am just having problems with nesting my Linq query.

Comment: What version of NHibernate are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would have been a lot easier if someone had an answer for me on this.

What I found out through trial and error...

Apparently through lazy loading it was not going back and loading the related tables I was referencing.  This was causing a null error and giving me no reference to "Site" error.

When I changed the loading from lazy loading to eager loading, there error went away.

So the moral to this story is that if the reference to a table where you are trying to use your nested where statement is null, you will get this error.